# ResponseEntity body attributes missing in Springboot with Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am developing a spring boot server and I am tryin to implement a custom exception handler for Validations

```
data class UserDtoIn(
    @field:NotBlank(message = "Please add a username")
    var username: String = "",
    @field:NotBlank(message = "Please add your password")
    var password: String = "",
    @field:Email(message = "Please add a correct email")
    var email: String = ""
)
```

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class ErrorResponse(
    val status: Int = 0,
    val message: String? = null,
    var stackTrace: String? = null,
    var errors: MutableList<ValidationError>? = null,
) {
    class ValidationError(
        private val field: String? = null,
        private val message: String? = null
    )

    fun addValidationError(field: String?, message: String?) {
        if (Objects.isNull(errors)) {
            errors = ArrayList()
        }
        errors!!.add(ValidationError(field, message))
    }
}
```

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    override fun handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        ex: MethodArgumentNotValidException,
        headers: HttpHeaders,
        status: HttpStatusCode,
        request: WebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Any>? {
        val errorResponse = ErrorResponse(
            HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(),
            "Validation error. Check 'errors' field for details."
        )
        for (fieldError in ex.bindingResult.fieldErrors) {
            errorResponse.addValidationError(fieldError.field, fieldError.defaultMessage)
        }
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(errorResponse)
    }
```

the response I got for a bad request is this:

```
{
    "status": 422,
    "message": "Validation error. Check 'errors' field for details.",
    "errors": [
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

Any opinions? The error response message is showing properly, but the Error objects seems to be null, but the entries are created for them. (in the inDto i have 2 bad fields and i have 2 brackets in the errors)

[in debug mode my errorResponse looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5BhC.png)

Comment: @RyuzakiL I have edited my questions and added a screenshot with the errorResponse in debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two fields you had in `ValidationError` class are `private`, basically for `private` fields as per java style `jackson` uses `getters` and `setters` for serialization and deserialization.

Since it's kotlin programming and they are defined with `val` keyword, you can  define them as public, and you don't need to assign `null` since the default it is default value for `String` type.

```
class ValidationError(
    val field: String?,
    val message: String?
)
```